# d3.behavior.zoom dynamic offset of mousewheel zoom center

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

Does anyone know how to dynamically modify the center property of d3.behavior.zoom in order to mousewheel zoom to a point offset from mouse position by specified x and y values?

The zoom should still track on the mouse position as usual, but offset by dynamically generated values.

I'm working with multiple coordinate spaces in a node tree plot using a library called webcola, which extends d3.  In order to implement smooth node dragging in addition to pan/zoom, I have buffered translate coordinates and merge them after node dragging. (rather than using the stopPropagation() method which is not implemented in cola).

The network drag + pan fix works, however that offsets the d3.behavior.zoom center. Now I want to offset the zoom target on mousewheel by specified x and y to restore proper cursor tracking on mousewheel zoom.

For example, if mouse is at position 100,100 but the coordinate space is shifted by 50,50, then mousewheel should zoom to 150,150, rather than actual mouse position of 100,100.

This offset target should be updated dynamically on pan/drag of nodes.

```
    function zoomCoords() {
        // generate the zoom coords based on the merged coordinate space - doesn't work
        console.log("d3.mouse");
            console.log(d3.mouse);
            return [0,0];
        }

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.2, 3])
        // .center(zoomCoords()) // set dynamically ??? 
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    svg.call(zoom);
```

......

```
    function zoomed() {
        if (enablePanning === true) {
            // we're dragging on the background, not a node.
            // zoom.center=newCoords; // doesn't work       
            // zoom.center(newCoords); // doesn't work              
            newCoords=[(d3.event.translate[0]-translateBuffer[0]),(d3.event.translate[1]-translateBuffer[1])];              
            container.attr("transform", "translate(" + newCoords + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        } else {
            // dragging on a node. save the translation to apply to the next container drag
            translateBuffer[0]=(d3.event.translate[0]-newCoords[0]);
            translateBuffer[1]=(d3.event.translate[1]-newCoords[1]);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: [`zoom.center()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#center)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff that sets it to a fixed point, or if null to mousewheel position. Does not allow dynamic offset from mouse position. I tried calling that within zoomed() and it doesn't work. Always zooms to 0,0.

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't be too difficult to modify the source and allow to pass a function that allows you to do that.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Perhaps, but hopefully there is a way without resorting to that.

Comment: Don't see one to be honest. My suggestion would have been to set the center dynamically inside the zoom handler, but you've tried that already.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff in case you're interested I found a solution to this that doesn't involve modifying the source (below)

Comment: Ah, interesting. I would attach the handler to click and wheel events though as those are the ones that trigger the zoom and don't continuously update the center (that may decrease performance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this without modifying the d3 source, by setting zoom.center on mousemove with my buffered translation offset values from each node drag event.

```
    function mouseMove() {
        m = d3.mouse(this);
        // apply the translate buffer so mousewheel zooms on the correct point after dragging the graph
        pt=[ m[0]+translateBuffer[0], m[1]+translateBuffer[1] ];
        zoom.center(pt);
    }


    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.2, 3])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    svg.call(zoom)
        .on('mousemove', mouseMove);
```